# References about "algebras over monoids"

Tags: category-theory, modules, monoid, monoidal-categories, algebras

Please, could someone point me any reference (with a bit of details) about "algebras over monoids" (in the sense of Schwede & Shipley, Algebras and modules in monoidal model categories)? Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not really specific, so I'm not sure if the following helps you: Chapter I of

> Florian Marty, *Des Ouverts Zariski et des Morphismes Lisses en Géométrie Relative*, PhD thesis, 2009

Edit: I've looked a bit at the paper you mention. They make heavy use of the notion of an algebra over a *monad* aka *triple*. You will find more about this notion in Mac Lane's *CWM*.  You may also look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28category_theory%29).

Comment: Florian's thesis was very useful, thank you! Algebras over monads are well-known for me, but thank you again.